# Translation of "People less fortunate than us"

Tags: traduction, adjectifs

How can we say “people less fortunate than us” for example in terms of condition, wealth, health, etc.

> La solidarité, il s'agit d'aider des gens moins fortunés (moins chanceux? moins heureux? avec moins de chance?) que nous.

Side question: Do we say “La solidarité, il s'agit…” or simply “Solidarité, il s'agit…”?

Comment: In addition to other translation proposals for "less fortunate" I would suggest "moins bien lotis".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering the side question, an even better way to say this  would be :

> La solidarité consiste à aider les gens moins fortunés que soi.

"soi" refers here to the person(s) showing solidarity.

Comment: OK with the translation, but depending on the kind of solidarity other adjectives might well fit. And as a side remark, solidarity is not necessarily help, it might also be standing together for example, but that's more of a philosophical subject...

Comment: You're right, there are many different aspects of solidarity ! And wealth sharing is only a little part of it. I wasn't giving a definition of solidarity in French, juste improving the translation posted in the question.

Comment: indeed, this is answering the question, therefore +1. My comment should have been made on the OP's post I agree...

Comment: I would mean solidarité in general, as in one would use to explain fraternité in the motto.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest one of:

> − La solidarité consiste à aider des personnes moins privilégiées que nous.
>
> − La solidarité consiste à aider des personnes dans le besoin.
>
> − La solidarité consiste à aider des personnes ayant moins de chance que nous.

*Fortuné* means in modern French almost exclusively "possessing a large amount of money" so doesn't properly match the English "fortunate" (lucky/happy/healthy/...)

Curiously, *Infortuné* has kept its original meaning so does match the English "Unfortunate".

Answer (score 0):

**La** solidarité, il s'agit d'aider des gens moins **fortunés** que nous.

**Fortuné**(singulier) : Someone who have a lot of money.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted because in my opinion the sentence is not correct. "La solidarité consiste à..." seems more correct, and if I wanted to stay simple, I'd say : "La solidarité, c'est de..."